# Xcode project gone bad - forgets the device and arbitrarily cancels builds

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an xcode project that's suddenly gone bad. I can only run on a physical device once, before it forgets the device is attached and offers only 'iOS device' next to my selected scheme. Worse still, 2/3 builds are cancelled for no reason:

[image: xcode]

If I try to rebuild or run (either on simulator or device) again a few times, eventually it works. But there's no clear pattern.

Any ideas what might be wrong? I'm currently using Xcode 4.6.1 on Retina MBP.

Comment: Usually when weird things like this happen, the only thing that helps is restarting the computer. This has happened to me before and I've tried restarting XCode, clearing all data from the iPhone and Simulator, and Cleaning the build but none of these worked. I would suggest trying them if you haven't yet, but if nothing works, try a restart.

Comment: Best guess, a bug. Create a new project, copy your code over and get rid of that bad little project.:) off course you can always try the method that js offered and then when you don't get any result try my method. :)

Comment: I've restarted many times, cleaned the project infinite times. Maybe rehousing the code is the only solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also try deleting derived data - go to Xcode's organizer, click on projects, click on your project, and hit the delete button where it says 'derived data'.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it! Thank you!